# How to create or update more than one objects of different models from one end point

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How to update more than one object of different model types from one end  point. I tried it many ways but i still fails.I tried through nested serializer and create method, but it is still not working

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    sex  = models.CharField(choices=SEX_CHOICES,max_length=255, 
    null=True)
    Category = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Registration(models.Model):
    registration_no = models.CharField(max_length=255, 
    unique=True)
    student = models.OneToOneField(Student, 
    on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name='registrations')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.registration_no

class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Registration
        fields = '__all__'    

class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'

class StudentDataMigrateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    student = StudentSerializer()
    registation = RegistrationSerializer()
```

Comment: what's the problem you're facing? isn't it saving the nested objects or something else?

Comment: My problem is that i want to create a viewset which will be able to accept the json array and migrate that data into the django model

Comment: Add the view and an example JSON request to the question, please.

Answer (score 0):

In Django Rest Framework by default the nested serializers are read only. To have a writable nested serializer you need to implement `create()` and/or `update()` methods.
Take a look at the official documentation https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

```
class StudentDataMigrateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    student = StudentSerializer()
    registation = RegistrationSerializer()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # save the data
```